# How to stream video using xuggler and Red5 in java?

Tags: java, video-streaming, red5, xuggler

I have installed both red5 and xuggler properly but unable to run both in fix.
How can we use xuggler library to stream video through the red5 server?

Is there any tutorial available online?
Or is there any other way to stream video and audio in java?